# SQL command not properly ended adding Having to limit data set to display

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, group-by, having-clause

i am working on limiting a data set to only include the rows where the sum(a)+sum(b)>avg(a.inv) what am I doing wrong here?

```
`SELECT a.product pno,substr(b.descriptn,1,40) pdesc, 
avg(a.inv) i,avg(a.badinv) q, avg(a.wipc) invc, avg(a.wipq) 
invq, sum(a) suma, sum(b) sumb, sum(c) sumc, sum(d) sumd
FROM temp2 a, mastertbl b 
a.product =b.product 
GROUP BY a.product, b.descriptn 
HAVING sum(sum(a)+sum(b)) > avg(a.inv)
ORDER BY a.product;`
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested `sum()` is not needed in the `having` clause. Your probably want:

```
HAVING sum(a) + sum(b) > avg(a.inv)
```

Side note: always uses standard, explicit joins rather than old-shool implicit joins - and, as it is, your query is missing a `WHERE` clause. Also, meaningful table aliases make the query easier to write and read. I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT 
    t.product pno,
    substr(m.descriptn,1,40) pdesc, 
    avg(t.inv) i,
    avg(t.badinv) q, 
    avg(t.wipc) invc, 
    avg(t.wipq) invq, 
    sum(a) suma, 
    sum(b) sumb, 
    sum(c) sumc, 
    sum(d) sumd
FROM temp2 t
INNER JOIN mastertbl m ON m.product = t.product 
GROUP BY t.product, m.descriptn 
HAVING HAVING sum(a) + sum(b) > avg(t.inv)
ORDER BY t.product
```

In this multi-table query, you should be qualifying *all* columns names with the table they belong to: this applies to columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      t.product pno,
      substr(m.descriptn,1,40) pdesc, 
      avg(t.inv) i,
      avg(t.badinv) q, 
      avg(t.wipc) invc, 
      avg(t.wipq) invq, 
      sum(a) suma, 
      sum(b) sumb, 
      sum(c) sumc, 
      sum(d) sumd
    FROM temp2 t
    INNER JOIN mastertbl m ON m.product = t.product 
    GROUP BY t.product, m.descriptn ) 
WHERE suma + sumb > i
ORDER BY pno
```